# How does jQuery`s .html() work with JavaScript strings?

Tags: jquery, html, ejs

I have express application, and EJS as view engine.
I am trying to set some html to div in 2 different ways:

```
const attachmentFileNames = '<%= eco.attachmentFileName %>';
if (attachmentFileNames) {
    $("#attachmentFileNameList").html(attachmentFileNames.replace(',', '<br/>'));
}
```

and

```
const attachmentFileNames = "<%= eco.attachmentFileName ? eco.attachmentFileName.replace(',', '<br/>') : '' %>";
if (attachmentFileNames) {
    $("#attachmentFileNameList").html(attachmentFileNames);
}
```

The thing is that first peace of code is working as expected ('< br/>' is treated as line terminator), but the second one just sets all data as a text ('< br/>' is displayed as string).

Could anybody please explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not jQuery's `html` function, it's EJS, which is automatically escaping the text produced by your `<%= ... %>` expression.

In your second example, if you look at the value of `attachmentFileNames` in the debugger, you'll presumably see `&lt;br/>` (or `&lt;br/&gt;`) instead of `<br/>`. When you use `"&lt;br/>"` (or `"&lt;br/&gt;"`) as HTML, the result is the characters `<`, `b`, `r`, `/`, and `>`:

```js
const attachmentFileNames1 = 'one,two';
if (attachmentFileNames1) {
    $("#attachmentFileNameList1").html(attachmentFileNames1.replace(',', '<br/>'));
}

const attachmentFileNames2 = 'one&lt;br/>two';
if (attachmentFileNames2) {
    $("#attachmentFileNameList2").html(attachmentFileNames2);
}
```

```html
<div id="attachmentFileNameList1"></div>
<div id="attachmentFileNameList2"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```